# Converting Gregorian Calendar to String but throwing an exception

Tags: java, tostring, gregorian-calendar

After running the program and trying to display the purchase date the program throws an exception
here is the code for getters and setters for purchase date:

```
public void setPurchaseDate(String purchaseDate){
    String[] dateSplit = purchaseDate.split("/");
    int month, day, year;
    month = Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[0]);
    day = Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[1]);
    year = Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[2]);
    GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar (year, month-1, day);
}

public String getPurchaseDate(){
    String date;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/DD/YYYY");
    date = sdf.format(this.purchaseDate.getTime());
    return date;
}
```

this the exception from the console:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at jasonsiboleproject5.motorVehicle.getPurchaseDate(motorVehicle.java:88)
at jasonsiboleproject5.car.toString(car.java:69)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2847)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:128)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:458)
at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2847)
at java.io.PrintStream.println(PrintStream.java:821)
at jasonsiboleproject5.mainclass.main(mainclass.java:83)
```

Java Result: 1

Comment: **Always** provide the exception and the stacktrace.

Comment: Now read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) and notice you haven't actually set a `purchaseDate` field in your `setPurchaseDate` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) First check for the format you have passed, is it valid `"MM/DD/YYYY"` or use this `"MM/dd/yyyy"`.

2.) Also in your `function setPurchaseDate`, you have `not set the date`, and in `getter` we are calling `this.purchaseDate.getTime()`, where `this.purchaseDate` will be null. So first set the value properly and also add a null check.

Comment: Thanks! I've been working on this way to long today and can't notice my simple mistakes.

Comment: @jscincy1 pls accept/upvote the answer if it  has really helped you.